# Restricting certain actions in a directory

Tags: security, chroot

So i have a web project, its a website that gives certain problems and the users try to find a solution using the C language, the compiling process is done by PHP, what i want to know is how can i protect my server against malicious programms that are written in C.
I done some researches and i found something called `chroot jails` and a command in linux `chroot` ,i read some documentation but i didn't understand it quiet well.
I'll be thankfull if anyone could help me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the programs run as a dedicated user (maybe one per program, depending on your requirements) and only allow it to read/write/execute in a dedicated directory.

chroot requires root provileges, so it isn't applicable here.

Comment: how can use these dedicated users ?? 
is it by creating new users in the system or what ?